# about a quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-computation, quantum-information

Consider the following circuit :
[image]

where $|\psi\rangle$ is a qubit in $\mathbb{C}^2$, $|0\rangle= \begin{pmatrix}1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$, $T= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & e^{i\pi/4}
\end{pmatrix}$ is the $\pi/8$ gate, $H= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ is the Hadamard gate, $X= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $P= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & i
\end{pmatrix}$.

In this circuit, the $PX$ gate is only applied when the measurement of the top wire outcome is $1$. This measurement is done with respect to the computational basis $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$.

The task is to verify the resulting state from this circuit, but it doesn't seem clear how we can retrieve $T|\psi\rangle$ exactly.

Note that: $TH|0\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}T\begin{pmatrix}1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\
e^{i\pi/4}
\end{pmatrix}$ then after the CNOT gate: $\text{CNOT}(TH|0\rangle|\psi\rangle)= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0& 0& 1 \\ 0 & 0& 1& 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\
e^{i\pi/4}
\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}\psi_0\\
\psi_1
\end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0& 0& 1 \\ 0 & 0& 1& 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\psi_0\\
\psi_1 \\
e^{i\pi/4}\psi_0 \\
e^{i\pi/4}\psi_1
\end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}\psi_0\\
\psi_1 \\
e^{i\pi/4}\psi_1 \\
e^{i\pi/4}\psi_0
\end{pmatrix} $

is not necessarily a separable state.

How do you go from here? The measurement is done on the top qubit only.

Comment: This question is better suited to the quantum computing stack exchange. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/